# Loading multiple views in cordova app

Tags: cordova, ngcordova

I want to be able to load multiple views in an cordova app using AngularJS. Could not find any samples for this.

All what i found is pure AngularJS Apps that does not work when i load it an cordova app.

For example:
Main Page
Tab1 --> load tab1.html partial view
Tab2 --> load tab2.html partial view

I want to know what can i have in the main controller and how to handle routing that actually works in cordova app using angularJS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i created "PlayGround" for Cordova app repo in git hub, you can access it here:

https://github.com/melzoghbi/CordovaApps